# ROR Form_for force to create action

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a search model which is used to create searches which are stored in the database by the create action and then redirected to @search where the results are displayed along with the search parameters.

I want to be able to from this view (url searches/:id) post a new search to create search :id+1 so the user can refine their search parameters.

I would like to be able to use the same form_for on both currently it looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@search, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
```

and renders as such:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/searches" class="form-horizontal" id="new_search" method="post">
```

Which creates the new search but on the show view it displays this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search?id=9" class="form-horizontal" id="edit_search_9" method="post">
```

how can I update it to force it to render the first way on all pages?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have a route that matches `/search`?

Comment: im new to rails please can you elaborate on what that route should look like.

Comment: Clarified this in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing the form tag id to the html hash, and override the default url to match the desired action.  Here's an example assuming you have a route named 'searches' that matches '/searches'

```
<%= form_for(@search, :url => searches_path, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal", :id => 'new_search' }) do |f| %>
```

To make a route in Rails, make this entry in your config/routes.rb file:

```
resources :searches
```

Comment: Is that no the wrong way around? should it not be:      <%= form_for(@search, :url => search_path, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal", :id => "new_search" }) do |f| %>

Comment: @user2732663, correct - I misread which was the actual result and which was the desired result.  Updated.

Comment: Thanks that really helpful, I don't fully understand how to set the correct route for this. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you see the file called 'routes.rb' in your application config directory?  You simply need to add a line in that file as I have it above (anywhere between the `YourApplication::Application.routes.draw` line at the top and the `end` line at the bottom).  Read up on routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get a better idea of what this is.

Comment: so close, it seems to be issusing a patch request rather than a post which means the router falls over.                                                                searches_path  GET  /searches(.:format)  searches#index
POST  /searches(.:format)  searches#create